# How to integrate react?

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

I am working in a team where everyone is new to web development. We have set up our database and routes. Now we want to use react for our front-end part. Should we use create-react-app to make a folder within the root directory. For example, the root directory has routes, controllers, models and then add the react app folder as the fourth folder? Or are we doing it wrong?
[image: Edit based on MukeshKumars suggestion. All folders. Currently, I just used create-react-app to make one additional directory]

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xq9XkCyWBTw

Comment: Which language are using for server side I mean are you using node.js or php for server side. And please can you add a screen short of you project folder.

Comment: @mukeshkumar we are using nodejs

Comment: Ok you need to create a client folder inside you main project directory.

Comment: Inside your project directory   npm create-react-app client
cd client  npm start

Comment: okay thank you!! I did just that, just named it "react-app" for now

Comment: Please check https://pasteboard.co/IxLZu5y.png in this image. And inside client directory your https://pasteboard.co/IxM1iQ5.png.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to manage frontend and backend directory structure.

1. Make backend directory structure and create `client` folder in it and manage your frontend in it.
2. Manage backend and frontend part seperately.

Most developers prefer separate directory for backend and frontend.

Answer (score 0):

You should keep your project Front end and back end modularized. Meaning, have a directory specific only to the front end, and a directory specific to back end. This will ensure you don't have a mess when you're building more routes and components and have to import things from various different folders.

So no, you probably don't want to place the react project inside of your root folder for the backend.